# Writing a line between lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a script where I have to insert a line between two lines. For example:

```
<tag1>
    <subtag1>     
           Line 1 - with some text 
           Line 2 - with some text
    </subtag> - #closing of subtag

**--> here i have (between closure of subtag and tag1) to insert a new tag (3 lines, opening tag, body and closing tag)**

</tag1>
```

I am trying the below-mentioned code, but I am not able to write anything in the file.

```
 with open ('abc.xml' , "r+") as f:
     for line in f:
         if '</subtag>' in line:
             f.write('\n text1\n')
             f.write('text2')
             f.write('text3')
```

Can somebody please let me know where in the above code I am doing it wrong, or any other idea to write a code for inserting a line between two lines in a file in python?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to read the whole content of the file (e.g. as a list of lines), *manipulate it in memory*, then write it back out *over* the previous file. Inserting into the middle of existing files in-place is not practical.

Comment: Hey .. thanks jonrsharpe for your input! . It worked after manipulating the file in memory and then over-writting it on existing file.

Answer (score 1):

As per *jonrsharpe*'s comment, the most easy to understand approach is to read the whole file, then insert lines where you need them:

```
# Let's read our input file into a variable
with open('input.html', 'r') as f:
    in_file = f.readlines()  # in_file is now a list of lines

# Now we start building our output
out_file = []
for line in in_file:
    out_file.append(line)  # copy each line, one by one
    if '</subtag>' in line:  # add a new entry, after a match
        out_file.append('    <some new tag>text1</some new tag>\n')

# Now let's write all those lines to a new output file.
# You would re-write over the input file now, if you wanted!
with open('out.html', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(out_file)
```

I started with this file:

```
<tag1>
    <subtag1>
        Line 1 - with some text
        Line 2 - with some text
    </subtag>
</tag1>
```

End my script produced this:

```
<tag1>
    <subtag1>
        Line 1 - with some text
        Line 2 - with some text
    </subtag>
    <some new tag>text1</some new tag>
</tag1>
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: hey .. thanks Symmitchry for your input!. Your code worked fine and now i am able to edit the file as required. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it worked. Make sure when you post a question you remember to "accept" the answer that worked for you, to help others understand how you solved your problem (and give me those precious points!)